# Not Work jQuery After Load via jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, click

I use two jquery

First click on "First" and show content

After click on "Twice" But not show content

This Link For My Code :http://jsfiddle.net/cFxsa/

Code :

```
$(function(){
    $('.first').click(function(){
        $('#load').html('<a href="#" class="second">Twice</a>');
    });

    $('.second').click(function(){
        $('#twice').html('<a href="#" class="third">Third</a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: At the moment you are binding the event handler to `$('.second')`, no such elements exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`click` can be attached only to exsiting elements, `.second` is being added after you tried to add it a callback, `on` support `delegation events` :

```
$('.first').click(function(){
    $('#load').html('<a href="#" class="second">Twice</a>');
});

$('#containerId').on('click', '.second', function(){
    $('#twice').html('<a href="#" class="third">Third</a>');
});
```

[**Fixed Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cFxsa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".first").click(function() {
   $("#load").html('<a href="#" class="second">Twice</a>');
});
$(document).delegate(".second","click",function() {
    $("#twice").html('<a href="#" class="third">Third</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reasign the .click() for $('.second')  after the $('.first').click() because the .html() insert a new things.
For easier use the function like :

Function firstClick(){
  -- your code
}
Function secondClick(){
  -- your code
}

Can be easier to reasign..just call 'secondClick();'

Hope this will help.. :)